# Bash Query: how to append string variable to end of a specific line dictated by a int variable?

Tags: sed

This is the code for appending string to a specific line number:

```
sed -e '1s/$/has/' -i testapend.txt
```

However, how would you be able to do the same thing but using a variable for the string and for the line number (int)?

I have so far tried inserting `$variable` into the slashes and chucking in braces, but it either says unknown command or extra characters after the command.

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk
So like this? Because it is not working.

linenum=3

append="Hello"

sed -e '/"$linenum"/ s/$/"$append"/' -i testapend.txt

I have also tried using sed -e "/$linenum/ s/$/$append/" -i testapend.txt and its still not working.

Comment: almost there: `sed -e "$linenum s/$/$append/"`  (untested)

Comment: However, if `append` contains a `/`, the s/// command becomes invalid syntax.